カスタムタクソノミーのタームに設定した説明文やアイキャッチ画像を一括登録する方法
カスタムタクソノミーに設定した複数のタームにおいて、説明文、アイキャッチ画像を一括で登録する方法を知りたいです。
以下のプラグインを使ったやり方を調べていたのですが、Really Simple CSV Importerは投稿データのアップロードしかできないようで上手くいきませんでした。

Advanced Custom Fields
Really Simple CSV Importer

またすでにWordPress上に登録されたタームについてはIDなどを指定し、データを更新できるようにしたいです。
以下にアップロードCSVのキャプチャを記載します。
https://gyazo.com/791a9c1f7fcbf01feb8a774e5822d267
調べたこと
「WP Taxonomy Import」というプラグインを確認したのですがこちらでは画像をアップロードできないようで、他の方法を模索しております。
どなたかご教示いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。
